# Web service returns a full, correct answer but the response Source is empty

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I am using a dispatch client to access a web service. All my params are correct, there are no errors and, examining the response with Wireshark, I can definitely see that the correct response is received at the network layer. But at the java application layer, my response Source is empty.

```
public void testDispatch(QName serviceName, QName portName, String endpointAddress, String action) throws Exception {

    Service service = Service.create(serviceName);
    service.addPort(portName, SOAPBinding.SOAP11HTTP_BINDING, endpointAddress);

    String requestXml = buildRequestXml();

    Dispatch<Source> dispatch = service.createDispatch(portName, Source.class, Service.Mode.MESSAGE);
    dispatch.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.SOAPACTION_URI_PROPERTY, action);

    Source request = new StreamSource(new StringReader(requestXml));
    Source response = dispatch.invoke(request);

    Transformer copier = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
    copier.transform(response, new StreamResult(System.out)); 

}
```

I tried to transform to a DOMResult, same thing, an empty root node.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I would invoke the service with Proxy API, then compare the Soap messages.

There may be a difference in namespaces that prevent JAXB from proper unmarshalling.

Answer (score 0):

My working solution for the problem:

```
StreamResult xmlOutput = new StreamResult(new StringWriter());
Transformer copier = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
copier.transform(responseStream, xmlOutput);
System.out.println(xmlOutput.getWriter().toString());
```